# how to have a repeating calculation in a POSTGRES select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So part of my query is like this

```sql
select 
   column_a,
   0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * column_b))
```

let's say `column_b` has the value of `3`
is there a way to represent this line `0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * column_b))`  as this?

```
0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * 3)) + 0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * 2)) + 0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * 1))
```

Basically, for what ever value column_b has, the function repeats.  Is there a way to represent this in Postgres sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this calculation will find the sum of `0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * column_b))` repeated by the number of times in `column_b`, you could use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) to genera the increments to the amount in `column_b` before summing the result of this calculation eg.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
create table sample (
   column_a char(1),
   column_b int
);

insert into sample values ('a',3), ('b',2);
```

---

**Using generate_series to generate the possible numbers**

```
select 
    column_a,
    column_b,
    array(
        select b_val
        from generate_series(1,column_b) b_val
    ) as computed_column
from sample;
```

| column_a | column_b | computed_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 1,2,3 |
| b | 2 | 1,2 |

---

**Finding the sum of the repeated calculation**

```
select 
    column_a,
    column_b,
    (
        select sum(0.75 * power(0.93, (0.1428 * b_val)))
        from generate_series(1,column_b) b_val
    ) as computed_column
from sample;
```

| column_a | column_b | computed_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 2.203924916826077250 |
| b | 2 | 1.476883153703056500 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a6VUabAibR5rcGcCayYJyG/0)